# VBScript use Windows Visual Styles

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to tell a VBScript to use Windows Visual Styles, so that any form components use Windows themed ones rather than classic ones? For example, to make a MsgBox show a styled button rather than a classic 3D raised square one.

This:

[image]

As opposed to this:

[image]

Comment: What program are you using to run the script? Windows script host? HTA? A browser?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Windows Script Host (wscript.exe).

Answer (score 2):

In HTA applications, A simple `meta` tag will turn on Visual Styles:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="yes">
```

This trick has seemed to disappear completely from Google search results, leaving this S/O question at the top!

In the case where a VBScript `MsgBox` is the culprit, one would have to modify `wscript host` to use visual styles. But for the sake of the post, you can easily make your own replica of a MsgBox using an HTA file, and turning on visual styles. I created an exact replica based off your screenshot:

msgbox.hta:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>MsgBox Title</title>
 <META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="yes">
 <HTA:APPLICATION ID="Custom MsgBox"
     APPLICATIONNAME="Custom MsgBox"
     BORDER="thin"
     BORDERSTYLE="normal"
     CAPTION="yes"
     CONTEXTMENU="no"
     ICON=""
     MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
     MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
     SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
     SYSMENU="yes"
     SCROLL="no"
     WINDOWSTATE="normal"/>
 <script language="javascript">window.resizeTo(400,170);</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial;padding:20px 0 0 20px;background:rgb(180,240,230)">
 <p>MsgBox Body; lorem ipsum dipsum</p><br>
 <div align="right"><button onclick="window.close()" style="width:80px">OK</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's small enough where you could `echo` it into an hta file right from a batch script, if you wanted to.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, but if you want to customize other properties of a message box this may help: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/vbalert.shtml